# Search in arrays with for loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, search

I have to search in array items using for loop without any "method", "function" or "break" syntax. I wrote this code bud does not work!

```js
var array = [12, "Data", true, "S"]

var searchItem = "Data"

var i

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == searchItem) {
        console.log("Item Found")
    } else {
        console.log("Item Not Found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain "does not work!" with more specifics.

Comment: It works for me, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: This will be print:

Item Not Found
Item Found
Item Not Found
Item Not Found

Comment: @MasoodSadri Even when you click "Run code snippet", it works:) It does so because you want to log something to the console on every iteration.

Comment: It does't work! I mean this loops doesn't show jus ONE result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to decipher what you're after, but are you looking for something like this?

```
var array = [12, "Data", true, "S"];
var searchItem = "Data";
var i;
var found = false;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] == searchItem) found = true;
}

console.log(found?'Item Found':'Item Not Found');
```